# Capture and Save the Screenshot of a Window in MFC (C++)

Tags: c++, image, mfc, gdi+, atl

I want to capture the screenshot of a window in MFC and save it as an image file. Following the examples, I got something as below for it

```
OnSave()
{
    CRect rect;
    GetWindowRect(&rect);
    CImage* img = new CImage();
    img->Create(rect.Width(), rect.Height(), 32);
    HDC device_context_handle = img->GetDC();
    HWND hwnd = this->GetSafeHwnd();
    bool IsPrint =::PrintWindow(hwnd, device_context_handle, PW_CLIENTONLY);
    HRESULT res = img->Save(L"image12.bmp", Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
    img->ReleaseDC();

    delete img;
}
```

Doing this, I get the file with the correct dimensions but it is always black. I checked and the result saving (res) is also always 0.  I tried to check different examples online but I could not get this black image issue fixed. Is there a suggestion to modify this or do this differently?

Comment: Does your target window handle the [WM_PRINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-print) message? Unrelated, but since you are requesting that only the client area be printed, your destination image should be sized to the client rectangle as opposed to the window rectangle (as the code does).

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do it

```
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h;

    // get window dimensions for following vars.
    // Don.t know if you want all area or just client area,
    // so use GetClientRect or GetWindowRect accordingly.
    // These functions sometimes are not so obvious on what they do.
    x1 = /**/;
    y1 = /**/;
    x2 = /**/;
    y2 = /**/;

    // width and height
    w = x2 - x1;
    h = y2 - y1;

    // copy window to bitmap
    HDC     hWindow = (HDC) window.GetDC();
    HDC     hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hWindow);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWindow, w, h);
    HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL    bRet = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, w, h, hWindow, x1, y1, SRCCOPY);
    
    CImage image;
    image.Attach(hBitmap);
    image.Save(debug_dir + L"window.bmp", Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);

    // clean-up
    SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hWindow);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```